# CSS Default selection without JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

Ok so Ive got a very basic CSS tab content system, very neat and clean, but I want to be able to create a default state so the first tab div is open without selection neccesary?

Any ideas, I would like top avoid jQuery or JS but if it has to be done i will use it. Heres the coding:

```
<div id="bar">
<a href="#tab1">Home</a>
<a href="#tab2">About</a>
<a href="#tab3">Contact</a>
<a href="#tab4">Credits</a>
</div>

<div id="container">
<div class="main">
<div id="tab1">First tab element (HOME)...</div>
<div id="tab2">... the second tab element (ABOUT)... </div>
<div id="tab3">... third tab element (CONTACT)... </div>
<div id="tab4">... fourth tag element (CREDITS) </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and the style:

```
#bar a{padding:4px 6px; background:#E0E9FE; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold;}
#bar a:hover{color:#003366;}
/* Content Layers */
#container{background:#E0E9FE; padding:10px;}
div.main div {display: none}
div.main div:target {display: block}
```

Many thanks in advance for advice and help.

EDIT: I can get the first div to display, with help from everyone so far (Many thanks) I just need to make it disappear when i select an extra tab, heres the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HHrYc/

Comment: Add a class="tab" to every tab and a class="tab selected" to the selected tab, and then you can format .tab.selected separatly from .tab.

Comment: It might be worth looking at jQuery or plain Javascript for this, so you can use `addClass` or `removeClass` etc, as you can't easily do it with CSS - as all the solutions don't work, because the first item will always be visible even when you click on another tab item.

Answer (score 1):

Giving additional classes to your elements is always useful ;)

```
<div class="main">
<div id="tab1" class="first">First tab element (HOME)...</div>
<div id="tab2">... the second tab element (ABOUT)... </div>
<div id="tab3">... third tab element (CONTACT)... </div>
<div id="tab4" class="last">... fourth tag element (CREDITS) </div>
</div>
```

And the style:

```
div.main div:target, div.main div.first {display: block}
```

But the first element would always be visible and would have to hide behind the others. This could be achieved with `z-index`and absolute positioning.

Comment: Ok heres what i got http://jsfiddle.net/HHrYc/ still seems to be present though on other tabs

Answer (score 0):

Give your first item the additional style:

```
display: block
```

This will override the `div.main div {display: none}` style that hides them normally, as it is more specific.

Comment: I've tried that but it stays present when you select other divs? :s

Comment: The problem with this is that although the first div content will be visible when you load the page, it means it will always be visible, even if you click on other tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Give your first div a `display:block` property:

```
div.main div:first-child{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below CSS:

```
.main div {display:none;}
.main div:first-child {display:block;}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/E9qgP/)

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the `display: none` for `display: block` in the div.main div